is it free to create a LUTs in solana?
Does anyone know the cost of creating lookup address tables on the Solana chain? Is this free?
I found description about LUT  in solana cook book but not mentioned fee https://solanacookbook.com/guides/versioned-transactions.html#address-lookup-tables-lut

Address lookup tables are still accounts, and so you still need to pay rent in order to create and extend them.
There's no tool that will tell you the cost automatically, but you can calculate it offline and fetch it using solana rent.
The header for the lookup-table takes 56 bytes per https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/5eab6ae2b5aec6910bd5a00bfccc00614450bec7/sdk/program/src/address_lookup_table/state.rs#L18 and then 32 bytes per pubkey, so for 14 pubkeys, you would need:
56 + 14 * 32 = 504

And then you can get the cost:
$ solana rent 504
Rent-exempt minimum: 0.00439872 SOL


it's really nice for me, thanks
